# Cannot connect to Google Cloud Shell through Browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

When I click GC Shell in console, it just stuck at establishing connection.
Similar thing happened for ssh connect to instance in Compute engine THROUGH Browser.

However, I can ssh connect to my instance using Putty and other ssh clients. Besides, Google cloud shell and ssh connection work well using Browser in another computer.

Browser I used: Chrome.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Wei Hu, it seems that you have an issue with the browser itself. Have you tried to [clear](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) browser cache, use incognito,  [enable cookies](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), or disable your adblocker (if you have one)?

Answer (score 4):

It's a weird problem on chrome. Most of time clearing cache will fix your problem. Clear your cache by going to **menu - more tools - clear browsing data** ( alternatively you can  press **cltr + shift + del** on windows ).

Answer (score 1):

For info, whitelisitng the GCP website in AdblockPlus in Firefox solved exactly this problem for me.